# Copy events from child elements to different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to copy a div content from one place to another, for this I am using something like:

```
$('#newDiv').html($('#oldDiv').html());
```

The problem is that some child elements have events attached using the bind() jquery method. I would want to copy also those events to the new location.

Any idea about a way to do this "event copy"?

Comment: Look at http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: jquery .on() is something you are looking for I guess.http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You create dynamic content in the moment you copy the content.

You need jQuery `.live()` or `delegate()` method to bind events to dynamically created html.

Choose `.live()` or `delegate()` depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

> **.live()** Available since jQuery 1.3. Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **.delegate()** Available since jQuery 1.4.2. Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VzDyg/)

#### Sample

```
<div id="newDiv"></div>
<div id="oldDiv"><a>click me</a></div>​

​$("a").live("click",function() {
   alert("click"); 
});​
    
// copy content
$('#newDiv').html($('#oldDiv').html());
```

​

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VzDyg/)

Comment: You should prefer `on()`, `live()` is deprecated (<1.7) ([link](http://api.jquery.com/live/))

Comment: you should prefer to avoid use of jQuery for trivial tasks, like event attaching.

Comment: `delegate()` or `on()`, not `live()` according to the [API for `live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/): "Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`."

Comment: @tereško why and what alternatives you mean ?

Comment: @dknaack , something like this http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/5mMP6/ . The advantage here is much smaller script , which works a lot faster then jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jquery Clone method you can set a parameter specifying if you want to keep events or not... check out: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

It should do nicely.

Comment: I have tried to do this with clone, but after copying the div #oldDiv I am loading a different content in it using load() and the new content appears in both #oldDiv and #newDiv divs.